# Does this triangle have a name?

Tags: terminology, triangles, plane-geometry

For any triangle $A$ (black below), form an enclosing triangle $B$ with sides
perpendicular to $A$'s angle bisectors (red).
Does this triangle $B$ (blue) have a name?

[image: Triangles]

A nod to vonbrand's question: This came up in exploring geodesics on a tetrahedron. It would take me far afield to explain more fully.

Comment: Just curious: Where does this come up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could possibly call it the [Anticevian triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnticevianTriangle.html)
with respect to the incenter,

Edit: Using the above and google  it seems it is called the
[Excentral triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExcentralTriangle.html).